# Laravel 5 , CLass HTML not find even after updating app.php and config.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have updated my Laravel5 with following code

**in app.pho**

```
providers array 
     'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',

    'aliases' => [
            'Form'=> 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
            'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

**In Composer**

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "illuminate/html": "^5.0"
    },
```

Then I update the composer with 
composer update

Still I am getting

```
Class 'html' not found
```

Can any one tell me what else could be wrong

Thanks

Comment: The package is now `laravelcollective/html`, for starters. http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html

Comment: @ceejayoz added according tot the tutorial still its saying class html not found :(

Answer (score 1):

@Vikram Sir..Actually i dont have enough reputation so that i can reply at your comment..so , i am updating my previous answer....sorry for my english..

```
**In app.php **
```

in providers array, add-

```
'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
```

in aliases, add

```
'Form'  => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
'HTML'  => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

now, 
in composer.json, add

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "illuminate/html": "~5.0."
    },
```

use ~ in the place of ^

now

on cmd,

```
composer update
```

100% working..

Comment: @RaghavendraPratapSing I have laravel 5.1.* so the HTML should be 5.0 or 5.1 ? , Please see my question I have written what I have updated in the file

Answer (score 0):

<del>Looks like your are using lowercase `html` instead of uppercase `HTML`</del>

Edit: Not that at all, Laravel 5 doesn not support HTML by default, you'll need to:

include `"illuminate/html": "5.*"` in your `composer.json`

Add the provider to `app.php`: `'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider'`

Add facades (alias part of app.php) to use `HTML` instead of the fully qualified name: `'Form'=> 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade', 'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade'`

Comment: where should I look for this , I am very new to laravel

Comment: this is how I write in my code  `{{ HTML::image('img/user-icon.gif', 'Sign In') }}`

Answer (score 0):

The answer was very specific to my problem .

I had to change ion my code

from

```
{ HTML::style('css/style.css') }
```

to

```
{!! Html::style('css/style.css') !!}
```

Comment: The capitalization is the issue, not the `{{` --> `{!!` switch.